# How to give static value to newly inserted rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, while inserting new records into that table I want to specify new static value for all those records. That static value should be same for all those records, again while inserting some other records want to give another new static value automatically.

```
Id name salary staticid
-----------------------
1  xyx  100     sh0001
2  ddd  200     sh0001
3  dfs  250     sh0001
```

While inserting new records I need output like this

```
Id name salary staticid
------------------------
1  xyx  100     sh0001
2  ddd  200     sh0001
3  dfs  250     sh0001
4  dsaf 320     sh0002
5  wew  650     sh0002
6  ter  365     sh0002
```

Thanks,

Comment: As posted this just doesn't make a lot of sense. Where does your "static" value come from? I would argue the value isn't static because it changes. Perhaps if you can explain where those values come from we can help you figure out a solution.

Comment: I will create user defined auto increment column, using function. So instead of giving auto increment to each row i want to give auto increment to all the newly inserted records

Comment: Do yourself a favor and forget trying to create a roll your own incrementing value. Use an identity. It already handles all the incredibly difficult edge cases for things like concurrency that are really hard to code correctly.

Comment: To answer your question, to insert the same value in multiple rows you would use either a literal or a variable as part of the values to insert.

Comment: can u tell me briefly how to get above output..

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing to do would be to insert your static value as you are filling your data/table.

```
DECLARE @staticValue varchar(100)
SET @staticValue = 'sh0001'

--Static Value 1 / Inserts
INSERT INTO dbo.tblA
    (Id, name, salary, staticid)
    SELECT 1,  'xyx',  100,     @staticValue
    UNION SELECT 2,  'ddd',  200,     @staticValue
    UNION SELECT 3,  'dfs',  250,     @staticValue

--Static Value 2  / Inserts
SET @staticValue = 'sh0002'

INSERT INTO dbo.tblA    
    (Id, name, salary, staticid)
    SELECT 4,  'dsaf',  320,     @staticValue
```

Another option, although it requires additional SQL Server permissions for [DDL - Data Definition Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx), would be to use a default constraint, as below

```
--Static Value 1 / Inserts
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblB ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_tblB_staticid DEFAULT 'sh0001' FOR staticid
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblB SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT

INSERT INTO dbo.tblB
    (Id, name, salary)
    SELECT 1,  'xyx',  100
    UNION SELECT 2,  'ddd',  200
    UNION SELECT 3,  'dfs',  250

--Static Value 2 / Inserts
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblB
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF_tblB_staticid  --Removes 'sh0001' default
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblB ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_tblB_staticid DEFAULT ('sh0002') FOR staticid
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblB SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT

INSERT INTO dbo.tblB    
    (Id, name, salary)
    SELECT 4,  'dsaf',  320
```

Comment: How is the data being inserted?

Comment: I written query for getting data from different tables and inserting into new table.

Comment: Look into my second suggestion/option, which involves [default constraints](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)